# How to change the views dynamically from one component to another in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

In my application I need to change the views from one component to another based on the parent component values.

View Structure

```
<app-component>
<app-common></app-common>
</app-component>
```

Here I call the common component as the child of app component.

```
<app-common>
<app-grid></app-grid>
</app-common>
```

Here I have the grid component as the child of common component

common.html

```
   <div class="accordion col-sm-12" id="accordion1" *ngFor='let data of dropdownData; let i=index'>
            <div class="accordion-group">

                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle h6" (click)="getCategory(categorycode.value)" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo + i">
                        {{data?.CAMD_ENTITY_DESC}}
                        <input type="hidden" #categorycode value="{{data?.PROD_PRCATG_CODE}}">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div *ngFor='let group of data.group; let j=index' id="collapseTwo + i" class="accordion-body collapse" style="margin-left:10px">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                            <div class="accordion-group">

                                <div class="accordion-heading">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" (click)="getGroup(groupcode.value)" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" [href]="'#collapseInnerTwo' + j">
                                        {{group?.CAMD_PRGRP_DESC}}
                                        <input type="hidden" #groupcode value="{{group?.PROD_PRGRP_CODE}}">
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <div [id]="'collapseInnerTwo' + j" class="accordion-body collapse" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:3px">

                                    <div class="accordion-inner" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="getSubgruop(subgroupcode.value)" *ngFor='let subgroup of group?.subgroup; let i=index'>
                                        {{subgroup?.CAMD_PRSGRP_DESC}}
                                        <input type="hidden" #subgroupcode value="{{subgroup?.PROD_PRSGRP_CODE}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <app-grid></app-grid>
```

it is an accordion from this user can choose the options like category,group,subgruop so every user select the values is need in grid component to display the views(API call will get data from db in grid component for every selected values) dynamically while user selecting the options.

common.component.ts

```
export class CommonComponent {

  categorycode :string ='';
  groupcode :string= '';
  subgroupcode:string='';

  constructor(private router: Router, private CartdataService: CartdataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  public getCategory(categorycode){
    this.CartdataService.get_Category_Code(categorycode);
  }
  public getGroup(groupcode){
    this.CartdataService.get_Group_Code(groupcode); 
  }
  public getSubgruop(subgroupcode){
    this.CartdataService.get_Group_Code(subgroupcode); 
  }

}
```

grid.component.ts

```
  export class GridComponent {

  @Input() C_code: string;
  @Input() G_code: string;
  @Input() SG_code: string;

  products: any;



  constructor(private CartdataService: CartdataService, private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(
      () => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.CartdataService.get_Selected_Category_Of_Products(this.C_code,
      this.G_code, this.SG_code).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.products = data;
        });
      }

  ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChange) {
    this.CartdataService.get_Selected_Category_Of_Products(this.C_code,
      this.G_code, this.SG_code).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.products = data;
        });
  }

}
```

grid.html

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 column" *ngFor="let product of products;let i =index;">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img-top card-img-top-250 one">
                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid" [src]="product['IMAGE_PATH_1']" alt="image">
                <img routerLink="/my-cart" class="img-fluid two" [src]="product['IMAGE_PATH_2']" alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="card-block pt-2">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center card-text">
                    <span #Pname1>{{product?.ITEM_DESCRIPTION}}</span>
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{product?.PRODUCT_CODE}}">
                    <p class="font-weight-bold text-primary">{{product?.PRODUCT_PRICE}} &#8377;</p>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn  btn-primary col-sm-12 corner" routerLink="/my-cart" (click)="getProductName(Pname1)">
                    <strong>View Details</strong>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here the user selected dropdown values are passed to the service file.

As I mention above the grid component is child of common ,So on the page load the grid component shows the views as per the values in service file which are send by the common component .

now When the user selected some values from dropdown in common component that values are passed to the service file ,Based on that values I make a call to the API from  service file .

Now What I want to do is when the new values are came to the service file from common component  I want to change the views of grid component based on the new values .

If it is possible ,please guide me to solve .
Thanks

Comment: <app-grid></app-grid> -> why not pass the value that will change here as a model and handle on model change?

Comment: @VeselinDavidov How to trigger the grid component when the model values get changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GridComponent  create an @input field and then pass the value from the parent component. Something like that:

```
 @Input() inputValue: string;
```

Then you call the component like that

```
<app-grid [inputValue]="valueFromCommon" ></app-grid>
```

Here value from common is the coming value. I used two way binding here but if you don't want it changed back you can use one way binding.

Then to handle changes you have two options.

- The preferred method :)

In the grid component you can create such method (basically implement on change)

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log("new value:",changes);
    }
```

Here the changes objects hold the value that has changed,its previous value and its new value. You can process it anyway you want.

- The other method which I wouldn't recommend because is something like a hack

Create getters and setters for the @input field and handle the changes there

```
private _inputValue: string;

@Input() set inputValue(value: string) {    
   this._inputValue= value;
  // process new value here    
}

get inputValue(): string {    
    return this._inputValue;    
}
```

----- Edit with the actual code for your problem -----

In your example the way you load data in the grid component from a service makes it detached from the parent component. You load everything in ngOnInit() from the injected service. Instead you should pass the values you want from the parent component.

For example change these to inputs

```
export class GridComponent {

 @Input()  C_code: string;
 @Input()  G_code: string;
 @Input()  SG_code: string;
```

Then in ngOnInit don't take them from the service and use the ones that came from the parent component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.CartdataService.get_Selected_Category_Of_Products(this.C_code, 
          this.G_code, this.SG_code).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.products = data;
            console.log(data);
   });
}
```

Then to call the grid component use:

```
  <app-grid [C_code]="categorycode" [G_code]="groupcode" [SG_code]="subgroupcode" ></app-grid>
```

This way you will pass the values selected from the common component to the grid component. Now in order to handle changes of these values (the changes are propagated to the component automatically but if you have external logic on change you need to add it). So in grid component add that method:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
             this.CartdataService.get_Selected_Category_Of_Products(this.C_code, 
              this.G_code, this.SG_code).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.products = data;
                console.log(data);
       });
     }
```

Which basically does the same as ngOnInit - queries the service. That's what you want to do when a property changes - requery the service

Comment: OK upload it. Which part didn't you get? Create an input field and you can pass values to the component. Make ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)  method to handle changes and do some processing (if you need to)

Comment: add the html also

Comment: I wrote my comment but I haven't tested it. It should work. You can try it and play a bit with it. Basically you need to pass the values from the parent component instead of getting them from a service and handle onChange events

Comment: I tried to check the values are passed to grid compoment from common throw console but it shows a blank line ...What I need to do

Comment: Well I gave you the way - I cannot be bothered to write your program sorry ;) Play with it for a bit and it will work.

Comment: The ngOnInit is call the api and working nice but the onchange method is not working for me .

Comment: Did you make the method exactly ngOnChanges(change:SimpleChange) ? you need to import Simple Change. If you use different name (for example without the plural "s" in the end) it won't work.

Comment: I have re-posted the grid.component.ts code please check it

Comment: import { Component, OnInit, Input, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

Comment: Try to add  implements OnChanges  to the declaration of the grid component and a console.log into the ngOnChanges method. Do you  go into the ngOnChanges  at all ?

Comment: ngOnChanges is get called at the component loads first afterwards it is not get called

Comment: still I am facing the issue that ngOnchanges not called after the first load ,could you please guide me to fix it

Comment: There you imported the following let { Component, NgModule , Input, SimpleChanges } = ng.core; and the function is  ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChange) but it is worked there but in my case not working